# Preloading JPA/Hibernate entities to an in-memory cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, guava

at work we are using Java EE (WildFly) with an ever increasing workload. Persistence layer uses EJBs with JPA and Hibernate. One table (main data table) gets like 99% of the traffic and database size, while there are a bunch of others that are used to described the data.

It works, but sometimes it slows down, due to many description entities that have to be loaded while saving the data table entities. We can't seem to get the 2nd level Hibernate cache going, so we are currently looking into in-memory caching.

The basic idea is just a simple HashMap for each of the description entities I mentioned above. We are talking about 10 tables with 50k records total, so it wouldn't impact the database badly.

Load all of them at startup, put them in the HashMap, link them with other cached entities (Some description entities have relations between themselves). When one of the entities is updated, replace it in cache with an updated version. While the reside in the cache, they are evicted and should behave like normal POJOs.

We've also looked into some real caching solutions like JCache, Caffeine, etc, but aren't sure if we really need the features they offer.

Does any of this make sense? Or is it a stupid approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Second level caching of Hibernate will take care of all of that. It will transparently put objects into the cache and evict them if some transaction (of that application) changes data. 2nd level caching refers to caching of entity object in a cache. There also is a query cache, which makes use of the second level cache. Note that the query cache needs to be enabled on a per query basis though with `org.hibernate.query.Query#setCacheable`